# What is ^0 in golang?

Tags: go, bitwise-operators, twos-complement

I am seeing ^0 in the code base.

Example:

```
type stat struct {
  ...
  min int64
  ...
}

newStat := stat{min: ^0}
```

What does ^0 mean?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators):

> ^x    bitwise complement    is m ^ x  with m = "all bits set to 1" for
>
> unsigned x and  m = -1 for signed x

So `^x` inverts each of the bits in `x`, eg. `0101` becomes `1010`. This means that `^0` is the same as `~0` in other mainstream languages.

When using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent negative numbers (which most programming languages do), the value of the bitwise complement of zero (where all bits are 1) is -1. So this is a way to write:

```
newStat := stat{min: -1}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I am a Go beginner and I still have no idea what this means. What is ~0? What is bitwise complement? Could you please clarify? 

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The bitwise complement is take each bit from an data type and invert it. For example 0 in 4-bit binary is 0000 its bitwise complement is 1111. The same way that 10 in a 4-bit binary is 1010 and its complement is 0101.

Comment: For further reference, read on [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) in general.

Comment: Thanks very much. This might sound stupid but what is the point of a bitwise operation? why didn't they just write 

stat{min: -1} 

but instead had to go through this trouble to write ^0 ?

Comment: I don't know where did you get that piece of code, but my guess is: because they want to. That is not a very advanced thing to do, and shows a feature of the language. There are cases where doing bitwise operations are faster than simple arithmetic. You can google for example `xor eax, eax`. But that is definitely not the case in your example.

Comment: My guess: They're not using 'min' the way you'd normally think of an integer (to count things), they're using it as a set of bits. If the last bit is 1 it means something, if the second to last bit is 1, it means some other thing, etc. In Go, code of this style might use '1 << iota' for constants. Anyway '^0' arguably conveys "an integer with all bits set to 1" better than '-1' does.

Comment: By the way, it seems unlikely that '^0' is any faster (or slower) than '-1': I suspect the compiler just writes both of them as a literal 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: @MatrixFrog yes all constants are hard coded into the binary.

Comment: Does this mean that Go requires two's complement, or that it would add code to ensure the CPU returns -1 if it implements signed ints differently?